# How to call the endpoint with the required data using ajax and jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Actually I have a params : id, token, action:"hosts"

Some example like Getting host= "https://example.com/mnt/api/v1/store/1/actions"

1. How to pass the required parameters to the endpoint. (or) How to call end point with required data ?

Comment: plse dont down vote i want some suggestions or idea pls

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you are after, if you are after how to call that using jquery ajax, then it will be something like this. I haven't used jQuery for a while, but base on my memory this is what I used to write. Also you can find more information from https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
   url: "https://example.com/mnt/api/v1/store/1/actions",
   method: "post" // or you can use "get"
   dataType: "json",
   data: {
      id: 1,
      token: token,
      action: "hosts"
   },
   success: your_callback,
   error: your_callback
});
```

Comment: getting the data and displaying in the console can we update in the html those data need to be dynamic . actually for suppose i am displaying the data in the console . them it is having the image how to get that image from that console and how to display in the html page dynamically , If you know pls answer@user663976

Comment: Sorry can you elaborate more on this. I don't really get what you are trying to achieve. Console are usually used for debugging javascripts and not for display data. I hope you are not trying to gain access to some website and doing sneaking stuff?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the parameters to a function, add the variables to the url and then reference the url in the ajax call instead of the url address e.g.

````
``
function myFetchPostsByCategory(id) {
         var id = id;

          var new url = `/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=${id}`;
```
````